# Простой сервлет HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Tags: java, servlet

Здравствуйте,код сервлета:

```
package arver;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

/**
 * Created by 35717 on 30.03.2016.
 */
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.doGet(req, resp);
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.print("servlet");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.doPost(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Файл web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>arver.MainServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

структура папок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ответ сервера:

> HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
>
> type Status report
>
> message HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
>
> description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested
>   resource.
>
> Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Может кому поможет:
in your doGet() method, get rid of

super.doGet(req, resp);
The HttpServlet basically follows the template method pattern where all non-overridden HTTP methods returns a HTTP 405 error "Method not supported". When you override such a method, you should not call super method, because you would otherwise still get the HTTP 405 error. The same story goes on for your doPost() method.

Comment: Надо бы перевести.